# How to display attribute value on product details page magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to show color custom attribute on product details page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTidl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Got to admin -> Stores -> Attributes -> Product. Then edit color attributes.Now select the storefront properties tab.Now change the value of **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** drop down value No to Yes. Then clear your cache and check product detail page and you get color attributes in product detail page.